# Octave Forge knnsearch

Tags: matlab, octave, knn

I just got Octave Forge the other day, and am trying to run my MATLAB code. There's a line in my code that's giving me this error

```
warning: the 'knnsearch' function belongs to the statistics package from 
Octave Forge but has not yet been implemented.

Please read <http://www.octave.org/missing.html> to learn how you can
contribute missing functionality.
```

I've gone to the website and the knnsearch is missing, and I would have absolutely no idea how to implement it. My MATLAB code is as follows

```
[IDX,D] = knnsearch(histaxis,histaxis,'K',k);
```

where histaxis is a 7787x2 list of the positions of events and I choose k anywhere between 2 and 10000. The value I'm really interested in here is the distance to the kth nearest neighbour, D(:,k), the other information this gives is superfluous.

Is there another way to get this information that is available through Octave?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can consult the duplicate post for a scratch-made implementation of `knnsearch`.  It's written for MATLAB, but the way I wrote it is compatible for Octave too.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful.. I'm a little worried about the speed of it though - knnsearch is nice and fast and gets through comparing two lists of 7787x2 very quickly.. I'm not sure how quickly a for loop (or I guess I'll need a nested for loop?) will do it. But I'll give it a go :)

Comment: There are three implementations of `knnsearch` in the post - ranging from a simple `for` loop to using `bsxfun / permute`.  I show them all as a base of comparison and how you would implement by brute force.  Use the `bsxfun / permute` solution towards the end of the post as it's most certainly the fastest.  Good luck!